# Tools similar to Google Test for C++ unit testing?

Tags: automated-testing, unit-tests, test-automation-framework

Are there any tools similar to GoogleTest for the purpose of functional testing in C++. I plan to do them as part of Unit Testing and would like to know of other options available so that I can make an informed choice.

Comment: Are you just looking for other C++ unit testing tools, or is there something in particular about Google Test that you want?  If the former, I think this question would be better served in StackOverflow, where there are already questions like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/91384/unit-testing-for-c-code-tools-and-methodology and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/242926/comparison-of-c-unit-test-frameworks.

Answer (score 2):

They have a [pretty large list at Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_unit_testing_frameworks#C.2B.2B). Unfortunately I have not used any to date so could not provide any recommendation.